# Yii2 - import excel, edit as form

Tags: yii, yii2

if i want to upload excel file, and then edit it as a form - each excel field as a form field. Form can be submitted and then the file gets saved. 
I'm really running out of ideas. 
Maybe import xls file to array? Then make form fields from this array? Submit would somehow save the file? 
I would be greatful for any ideas.

Comment: What you had tried?

Comment: I got it to work using PHPExcel, had some fun with foreach and forms etc, it worked at the end.